# UITesting Failure - failed to get attributes within 5s: { 3003 }

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

Recently I have permanent error while perform UI testing. Why it happens? What may be the reason?

[image]

**IMPORTANT INFORMATIONS:**

- I reset the app, XCode, and even macbook. It doesn't help.
- Running tests on a real device, problem doesn't exist on simulator.
- it was very fine so far, it stopped working immediately...

What are attributes to get? How can I workaround this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply restart your device. It will work then.